# Color changed in firefox

Tags: firefox, 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and all of a sudden the color of the firefox history bar changed to a darker one

[image: attached image of it]

Not really the biggest problem, but I wonder why since it doesn't look like that on my other computer with Ubuntu 16.04.

Removing `~/.cache/mozilla` and `~/.mozilla` didn't do anything to it.

Cheers!

Comment: You can click on the settings then customize .. look for themes at the bottom and see if you have another theme available.  If not you may be able to chose get more and find one that is the older style

Comment: Ah, seems like the default changed in an update. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 46 switched to using GTK3 for Linux desktop builds and this is the reason for the change in background color.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/firefox-46-now-available-download