# How to change Firefox drop-down menu color?

Tags: unity, 15.10, firefox, themes

I've got the same problem as in [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767044/color-changed-in-firefox): after the system update, Firefox drop-down menus became black.  How can I change their color back to white?

(I'm opening a new question because that one didn't specify a question, and its author seemed satisfied with the reason explanation without the solution.)

Ubuntu 15.10, Ambiance theme of the default desktop environment.

Comment: You might try to simply install a firefox theme.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try a bunch of themes; they changed many things but not the menu color.

Answer (score 0):

In [another thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289881/how-to-change-dropdown-color-in-firefox-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment507234_289881) a user suggested a workaround: run Firefox (and only Firefox) with another theme:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita firefox
```

Works like a charm.